# asp.net default control colors

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Is there a simple way to change the default colors of controls in asp.net (VS2010).  Specifically, every time a textbox is moused over or a submit button is clicked, they get light blue highlights or borders.  This was fine until I made a light green site.  Now it really does not match at all.  Is there one simple place in VS2010 I can change this default color to green?

Thanks for any help....and yes I'm a noob!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS
If you're using a master page, just setup a default styles css file in the master page and set all of your css styles there, such as input, p, a, input[type="submit"], etc.
If you're not using a master page, define these in the .aspx pages
Here's a link to a CSS tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't provide CSS information for the controls in either a stylesheet, style tag or inline styles, then they will use the CSS as defined by the browser that you are using.

With that out of the way, you can style your controls in CSS based on their type:

```
input { ... }
input[type="text"] { ... }
input[type="submit"] { ... }
```

Comment: I think I got it now.  Thank you both!